# Adding property to custom UICollectionsViewCell causes app to crash (XIB based app)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a subclass of UICollectionViewCell. Right now it only has a label in its view. Without connecting the label to the files owner, the view controller runs fine. However, when I connect this label to the class's header file and try to change it's text through its property, the app crashes with this message:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSObject 0x7ff543180040> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key cellLabel.'
```

---

```
First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106744f35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000105fefbb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106744b79 -[NSException raise] + 9
3   Foundation                          0x0000000105b8c7b3 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 259
4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010668ee80 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 224
5   UIKit                               0x00000001072a7c7d -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1506
6   UIKit                               0x000000010761cf05 -[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:viewCategory:] + 588
7   MyApp                              0x00000001056853e1 -[ViewController collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:] + 113
8   UIKit                               0x000000010761041b -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:] + 244
9   UIKit                               0x0000000107611b54 -[UICollectionView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 3445
10  UIKit                               0x0000000107615801 -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews] + 243
11  UIKit                               0x000000010705b973 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 521
12  QuartzCore                          0x0000000106e6dde8 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 150
13  QuartzCore                          0x0000000106e62a0e _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
14  QuartzCore                          0x0000000106e6287e _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
15  QuartzCore                          0x0000000106dd063e _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 242
16  QuartzCore                          0x0000000106dd174a _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 390
17  QuartzCore                          0x0000000106dd1db5 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 89
18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106679dc7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106679d20 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010666fb53 __CFRunLoopRun + 1123
21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010666f486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
22  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001098029f0 GSEventRunModal + 161
23  UIKit                               0x0000000106fe2420 UIApplicationMain + 1282
24  MyApp                              0x0000000105696083 main + 115
25  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000109325145 start + 1
26  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

CustomCollectionViewCell.h

```
@interface CustomCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell    

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cellLabel;

@end
```

CustomCollectionViewCell.m

```
#import "CustomCollectionViewCell.h"

@implementation CustomCollectionViewCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
}

@end
```

ViewController.h

```
@interface CalculatorViewController : UIViewController <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionsView;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "CustomCollectionViewCell.h"

@interface ViewController () {
    NSMutableArray *sourceArray;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    sourceArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", nil];
    [self.drinksCollectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomCollectionViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}

#pragma mark - Collection view datasource

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return sourceArray.count;
}

- (CustomCollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    CustomCollectionViewCell *cell = (CustomCollectionViewCell *) [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.cellLabel.text = sourceArray[indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

Please help.

Comment: Reconnect IBOutlet connection and verify its type and name.

Comment: You have something wrong in your XIB file connection to outlet: maybe you connect to File Owner, not your custom cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't connect the outlet to the file's owner (in fact, leave the file's owner as NSObject). Change the class of the cell to your custom class, then connect from the cell to the label.